# jQuery Mobile: Collapsible not expanded in pageinit, when coming back from other page

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my jquery-mobile (1.0RC2) application, I have two pages: test1.html, test2.html

The first page, test1.html, includes an collabsible-set, where I expand one collabsible item via script in the pageinit event listener (tried both pageshow and pageinit):

```js
$('#page1').live( 'pageinit', initPage);
function initPage() {
    alert('initPage!');  // this line seems to be always getting executed
    $('#my_expandable').trigger('expand');  // ... but this line doesn't when coming back via a back link!
}
```

This works fine on the first call of the page.

Then I have a link that leads me to the second page test2.html, as follows:

```js
<script>
function goPage2(criteria) {
    $('#page1').die( 'pageinit', initPage);
    $.mobile.changePage( "test2.html", {reverse: false, reloadPage: true} );
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:goPage2('brand');" rel="external" class="ui-link-inherit" style="margin-top:0px;padding-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">page 2</a>
```

When I then go back to the first page via

```
<script>
function goPage1() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "test1.html", { reverse: true, reloadPage: true} );
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:goPage1();" rel="external" class="ui-link-inherit">test</a>
```

only the alert message in the pageinit event listener of test1.html is executed, but the collapsible is not being expanded through the

You can see the sample in action here: http://bit.ly/rr0dq3

**How to reproduce the problem:**

- load test1.html at http://bit.ly/rr0dq3
- you will get an alert message, and the collapsible will be expanded
- click on the button 'GoTo page2' and you will come to the second page test2.html
- on this second page, click on the gray button 'test', and you will come back to the first page test1.html
- the problem now: as you can see, the alert command of the pageinit event of test1.html is being executed, but expanding the collapsible isn't - why not? Obviously the pageinit event listener method is being entered properly, but only the collapsible seems to have a problem here.

I think it might be a bug (filed a report here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2791), but maybe somebody else has an idea for that.

**Workaround:**
Both the alert and the collapsible expanding is being executed when I use a different way to to open the second page test2.html, using

```js
window.location.href = "test2.html";
```

instead of

```js
changePage(...);
```

But it's not very satisfying. Why does it not work properly if I use the the page injection way? I already call the die() method when I open the different pages in order not to have multiple pageinit event listeners keeping hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `data-attribute` for collapsible content areas that makes them load expanded:

```
data-collapsed="false"
```

Here is a link to the docs for this behavior: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/content/content-collapsible.html

Comment: I know that attribute, but that doesn't meet my requirements. I need to expand or collapse the item dynamically via script, not fixed via attribute. Of course, my sample was very basic, but in my real application, I have multiple collapsibles, and depending on certain criterias, when the user goes back to the page, I need to expand/collapse some, some not.

Comment: The thing i found out what worked was  $.mobile.changePage( "test1.html",{changeHash: true}); but url shows not right then